# Sum up numbers in column using date completed as a filter

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum

I want to sum up some numbers in a column but only from items that have been marked as completed. These are checked off with the completion date in another column.

In this example, two articles have been completed "foo" and "baz". They have dates in the E column and I want to match up the corresponding row values in the B column. The uncompleted items have a blank cell. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you are looking for. Have a look at 3 of them.

Please try any of the following

```
=SUMIF(E2:E6,">0",B2:B6)
=SUM(QUERY(A2:E6,"select B where E is not null",0))
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER(B2:E6,E2:E6<>""),0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Super. The first option worked. Thanks